# Horizontal scrolling in Chrome Dev Tools elements inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So, one of the things I hate about the Chrome Dev Tools is this:

[image]

Basically, when the html is deeply nested the elements tab starts to wrap lines to try and fit everything in the panel, instead of using an horizontal scrollbar, which would make much more sense here.

I can't believe such an awkward layout is intended, it's literally unreadable... is there a setting to prevent this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found a setting in the DevTools that solved this issue:

If you uncheck **Word wrap** everything should be fine.

The setting is located here: *DevTools Settings > General > Elements > Word wrap*

[image]

Comment: I did exactly the opposite i.e. enabled word wrap in Chrome 80.0.3987.87 and that helped me out of the horizontal scroll hell at least so far.

Comment: Very useful response

Comment: I just toggled mine from *checked* to *unchecked* and it worked. Toggled it back to *checked* and still no horizontal scrollbar. Probably just a "glitch."

Comment: The location seems to be: Settings (gear icon) > Preferences > Elements section. I don't see anything labelled "General".

Answer (score 6):

Enabling word wrap technically solves the problem, but leads to another equally annoying situation, the "horizontal scroll hell" mentioned by user karvonen.

But it turns out Mozilla devtools avoids both problems quite ingeniously by only adding a horizontal scrollbar when the nested elements get too far. I switched to Mozilla devtools just for that:

[image]