# How to find the div that causes horizontal Scroll in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a huge site that has a bazillion elements in the DOM.

The CSS is quite messy, with overflows in a bunch of places. There are many things that can make the site wider than then 100% width of the viewport.

How do I figure out, what causes this?

### An anomaly

What's extra weird is, that I can see that there still is a horizontal scroll, if I delete all the elements in the DOM:

[image: Horizontal scroll in Chrome]

But I can see that on my phone that I still have some horizontal scroll.
I'm not sure if this is the site I'm working on that is faulty - or Google Chrome.

It doesn't occur in Safari (on Desktop). It doesn't even occur with elements in the DOM.

---

### How I currently debug this

Currently I go through the elements in the DOM and hover and see if I can find the culprit that is wider than it should.
It's a very tedious process.

### Solution attempt 1: Check Chrome settings

As mentioned, I'm not sure if this is a bug in Chrome or with this site.

I found [this post mentioning something about word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416841/horizontal-scrolling-in-chrome-dev-tools-elements-inspector), but that didn't help.

I also skimmed the Chrome settings.

### Solution attempt 2: A JavaScript script that lists all outer elements

I'm thinking that maybe it would be beneficial to make a script that checks the width of all div's on the site - and returns an array with the 10 widest, so I can skim down over it and spot the widest ones.

This might not be perfect, since a horizontal slider might be wider than it's parent div, but if it's inside of an `width: 100%; overflow: hidden;` div, then it shouldn't be counted. Hmm...

Comment: i see in your CSS file, body has relative position. is there any top or left attribute?

Comment: There is no `top` or `left` attribute, no. Position relative is set on body, so elements with `position: absolute` will position itself relatively to that.